# Cannot work out a simple operation on coordinates

Tags: coordinate-transformation

I am trying to substract a value, 172 from the x-value of a system of coordinates.

I try:

```
points = {{395.4416644777464`, 
    207.63931734339303`}, {391.15890276860114`, 
    240.47382378017346`}, {382.59337935031067`, 
    219.06001523444706`}, {378.3106176411653`, 
    209.0669045797748`}, {369.74509422287485`, 
    177.65998537937617`}, {361.1795708045843`, 
    250.4669344348457`}, {355.46922185905726`, 
    204.78414287062958`}, {346.9036984407667`, 
    236.19106207102823`}, {341.19334949523966`, 
    184.79792156128497`}, {332.6278260769492`, 
    220.48760247082885`}, {326.9174771314222`, 
    214.77725352530183`}, {322.6347154222768`, 
    260.4600450895181`}, {316.9243664767498`, 
    219.06001523444706`}, {314.06919200398636`, 
    241.90141101655524`}, {304.076081349314`, 
    119.12890868772422`}, {295.5105579310235`, 
    327.5566451994606`}, {278.3795110944425`, 
    156.24617683364988`}, {269.8139876761519`, 
    251.8945216712275`}, {264.1036387306249`, 
    196.218619452339`}, {258.39328978509786`, 
    286.1566153443896`}, {249.8277663668073`, 
    233.33588759826466`}, {241.26224294851679`, 
    173.37722367023093`}, {231.26913229384448`, 
    184.79792156128497`}, {224.13119611193568`, 
    286.1566153443896`}, {215.56567269364515`, 
    160.52893854279512`}, {199.86221309344583`, 
    303.28766218097076`}, {184.1587534932465`, 
    72.01852988712619`}, {172.73805560219247`, 
    587.3775222209401`}, {162.74494494752017`, 
    83.43922777818022`}, {149.89665982008435`, 
    260.4600450895181`}, {145.61389811093912`, 
    254.74969614399106`}, {138.47596192903032`, 
    317.56353454478824`}, {131.33802574712158`, 
    183.37033432490318`}, {124.20008956521278`, 
    193.36344497957543`}, {119.91732785606749`, 
    160.52893854279512`}, {112.77939167415872`, 
    214.77725352530183`}, {108.49662996501345`, 
    199.07379392510256`}, {105.64145549224995`, 
    250.4669344348457`}, {101.35869378310466`, 
    324.70147072669704`}, {98.50351931034115`, 
    224.77036417997408`}, {91.36558312843238`, 
    220.48760247082885`}, {81.37247247376007`, 
    96.28751290561604`}, {75.66212352823305`, 
    200.50138116148423`}, {72.80694905546954`, 
    351.82562821795045`}, {54.24831498250671`, 
    154.8185895972681`}, {41.4000298550709`, 
    240.47382378017346`}, {35.68968090954388`, 
    236.19106207102823`}, {32.83450643678037`, 
    280.4462663988626`}, {12.848285127435787`, 
    131.97719381515992`}, {7.1379361819087705`, 227.62553865273765`}};
```

and

```
data = {# - 172.73805560219247`, #} & @@@ points
```

however, this gives a wrong system of coordinates.

What is wrong with the "data=" command?
Thanks

Comment: It is not easy to find the info for three @ s on google

Comment: You probably want to do `{#1 - 172.73805560219247, #2} & @@@ data`, or `# - {172.73805560219247, 0} & /@ data`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sol1 = {#[[1]] - 172, #[[2]]} & /@ points ;

sol2  = points - Threaded[{172, 0}];

sol3 = MapAt[Subtract[#, 172] &, points, {All, 1}];

sol4 = {#1 - 172, #2} & @@@ points;

sol1 == sol2 == sol3 == sol4
(* True *)
```

Comment: I think `Threaded` suffered from poor performance (okay, not much of an issue in many cases) - I wonder if that has been resolved by now?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following variations:

```
TranslationTransform[{-172, 0}][points]

SubsetMap[# - 172 &, points, {All, 1}]

First@Last@Reap@Do[Sow[points[[i]] - {172, 0}], {i, 1, Length@points}]

points - ConstantArray[{172, 0}, Length@points]
```